# Reading file mtime in UNIX in particular format (2013-06-25 09:04:32)

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, dos2unix

hi i have this file on my UNIX box (SunOS 5.10).

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phnxep  siebel 917 Feb  1 02:52 crontest.sh
```

Here date and time are given like **Feb1 02:52**.Can i just read these values in **UNIX** for my file ignoring the rest of the details.In the required format-:

> 2017-02-1 02:52

And convert them to **integer** values later on???Please help guys i am really stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using gnu `ls`, try

```
ls -l --time-style=full-iso
```

E.g.:

```
$ touch x
$ ls -l --time-style=full-iso x
-rw-r--r-- 1 max max 0 2017-02-06 13:18:56.498920000 +0000 x
```

If you are using Sun `ls`, try `-E` option, e.g. `ls -E`.

Comment: where should i specify the file name?

Comment: @TusharSharma At the end of the line.

Comment: ls: illegal option -- time-style=full-iso
usage: ls -1RaAdCxmnlhogrtuvVcpFbqisfHLeE@ [files].It says this.how to check i am using GNU or not?

Comment: For Solaris `ls` try `-E` option.

Comment: Hey thanks sir it was really help full can you also tell me how can i convert them to integer values.after i use cut command and get them seperated??

Comment: @TusharSharma Now that you are able to get the file timestamp in ISO format, you should be able to parse it and convert to the number of seconds since UNIX epoch. You may like to ask another question regarding parsing.

Comment: ok Sir thanks a lot for your help.I will query again if i found any further issue.

Comment: hi sir can you tell me how can i convert  my file creation date to an integer value . For ex i have a file called "abc.txt" with creation date (2017-02-01) . I have this value in a variable. Now how can i convert it to something like (20170201).Thanks

Comment: @TusharSharma Search for "parse timestamp", there are plenty of answers.